# get rid of root layout's code in another route like, /docs

Tags: next.js, routes, next.js13

I'm using Next.js 13.4. In the `app/layout.jsx` file, I added the Navbar and Footer so it would be the same for all the pages.

But now, I have another route, `app/docs/page.jsx` where I want to get rid of the default Navbar and footer.

How to do that?

`app/layout.jsx`

```js
// Vercel Analytics
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
import "./globals.css";
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";

const layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="bg-gray-950 text-gray-200">
        <NavBar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
        <Analytics />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default layout;
```

I know why this is happening but I want them **not to** overwrite certain routes. How to do that?
I'm new in Next.js.

Live Demo: https://contest-hive.vercel.app

Github Repo: https://github.com/Nusab19/Contest-Hive

I've tried switching the code from `layout.jsx` to `page.jsx`, but that broke some other functions.

Now the /docs page looks like this: https://contest-hive.vercel.app/docs

The Navbar and Footer are there by default